# keep a button disabled until certain conditions are met

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have 5 `asp:TextBox`, the sum of values of 4 of them must never exceed from the value of 5th textbox. Until then, the button to submit must stay disabled.

Here are the controls

```
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalSecurityDeposit" MaxLength="9" runat="server" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onfocus="words.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" onkeyup="words.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" onfocusout="myFunctionn()"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

 <td style="width: 100px">

                <asp:TextBox class ="input" ID="txtAmount_VH" MaxLength="9" runat="server" Width="100px" Style="text-align: right" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onfocus="words.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" onkeyup="words.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" onfocusout="myFunctionn()"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 100px">

                <asp:TextBox class ="input" ID="txtAmount_MX" MaxLength="9" runat="server" Width="100px" Style="text-align: right" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onfocus="words.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" onkeyup="words.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" onfocusout="myFunctionn()"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 100px">

                <asp:TextBox class ="input" ID="txtAmount_OB" MaxLength="9" runat="server" Width="100px" Style="text-align: right" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onfocus="words.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" onkeyup="words.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" onfocusout="myFunctionn()"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 100px">

                <asp:TextBox class ="input" ID="txtAmount_SP" MaxLength="9" runat="server" Width="100px" Style="text-align: right" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onfocus="words.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" onkeyup="words.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" onfocusout="myFunctionn()"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
<td style="text-align: right">
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddAmount" runat="server" Text="Add" Width="92px" />
            </td>
```

And here's the jQuery function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type ="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.input').on('keyup', function () {
                $vhamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_VH%>').val();
                $mxamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_MX%>').val();
                $obamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_OB%>').val();
                $spamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_SP%>').val();
                $totamnt = $('#<%=txtTotalSecurityDeposit%>').val();

                $sum = $vhamnt + $mxamnt + $obamnt + $spamnt;
                If(parseInt($sum) > parseInt($totamnt)) Then {
                    $('#<%=btnAddAmount.ClientID%>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Chrome's console is also not dropping any clues.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a function which will hold your logic.
2. call that function from each textbox onblur event.

Comment: No. The same approach works for HTML controls, so why go through that.

Answer (score 0):

tested your code in mvc razor with few changes in **JS code** and it worked for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type ="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.input').on('keyup', function () {
                $vhamnt = $('#txtAmount_VH').val();
                $mxamnt = $('#txtAmount_MX').val();
                $obamnt = $('#txtAmount_OB').val();
                $spamnt = $('#txtAmount_SP').val();
                $totamnt = $('#txtTotalSecurityDeposit').val();

                $sum = $vhamnt + $mxamnt + $obamnt + $spamnt;
                If(parseInt($sum) > parseInt($totamnt)) Then {
                    $('#btnAddAmount').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Of course it did. There are no server side controls in MVC. My markup and JS code too works with HTML controls.